# Wordpress site loading issue

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress WooCommerce for my client site and when I upload to server (using Plesk Panel) site is configured but cannot load properly specially `menu and slider part.`

Any idea, what might be issue?

[Problem here](http://elegantkids.in.th/)

Same source works perfectly over this [demo server](http://kids.pspsolutions.info/)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I can't view/access either site. Would you provide more detail in your question?

Comment: yes just few mins, let me update with new source

Comment: well, not sure why but when i am changing database server url, it reset theme related customizations done by us and here needs to do same again one by one manually.. strange but this works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both those problems (slider and menu) sound like a jQuery /Javascript problem.
Sure enough - looking at your code  - The amount of Javascript and Jquery scripts on your site is overwhelming (I stopped counting after 45...)
To make things worse , some of them are overlapping (Easing .. Ui)  and some are actually duplicated (4 different types of sliders were counted)
This is a sure recipe for conflicts . 
Check again all loaded scripts , clean, and see if the problem persists ..